# Dynamically generate and name dataframes

Tags: r

I've seen a couple of other posts on this, and they've suggested loading dataframes into lists, however they've never explained what's an acceptable way to then name the dynamically generated dataframes.

I've come up with the code below and I want to know if it is a good way of doing this or if I will run into problems in the future?

Thanks,

```
#create the data frames from all csv files into a list
dfs <- lapply(list.files(pattern="*.csv"),read.csv)

#Give them the correct names
names(dfs) <- regmatches(list.files(pattern="*.csv"),regexpr("^[[:alpha:]]+", list.files(pattern="*.csv")))
```

Also, can I name them and create them at the same time? I don't want to run the risk that the list.files comes back in a different order on the second call and I put the wrong names on the dataframes.

Comment: I tried this and it worked well except for any .csv name that started with a numeric.

Comment: You are right, I should probably use a more robust regex that looks for .csv at the end of the filename. Other than that, is it robust? Is it correct? Is it elegant? Is it going to lead to problems down the road?

Comment: A different order can only occur if files get added, deleted or modified. You could simply store the return value of `list.files` in a (temporary) variable.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for the response. I actually thought of that, however I was wondering if I could create and name the dataframe in one step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Map` function will do a better job of automatically naming the elements.

```
dfs <- Map(read.csv, list.files(pattern="*.csv"))
```

Then you could further edit the `names()` of the list after it's generated. Or you can just save the file name vector  rather than calling `list.files()` multiple times and use `setNames` right away

```
#create the data frames from all csv files into a list
csvfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
dfs <- setNames(lapply(csvfiles, read.csv), 
    regmatches(csvfiles,regexpr("^[[:alpha:]]+", csvfiles))
)
```

Comment: So the second approach is very similar to mine and incorporates Roland's suggestion, but it uses setnames() instead of 'names() <-' right? Oh, and it also creates and names in one step! I like it, thanks.

Comment: Also if anyone wants to improve it as Stu suggested, I was playing around with the regex, something like:    regmatches(list.files(pattern="*.csv"),regexpr("[[:punct:]]csv$", list.files(pattern="*.csv")),invert=T). The only problem is that I was getting 2 characters for each name, the right one followed by a blank one.

Comment: What is the actual goal of your regex. It would help to give sample input and desired output. Seems like at least in the current version, just using `gsub` to remove non-alpha numeric values would be simpler. Perhaps you should ask a new question just focusing on your name cleaning problem.

Comment: Oh, the current regex is working perfectly for me. I was suggesting someone else might want to modify it and use [:alnum:] or match '.csv' and invert it if they might have numbers in the names of their files. For me, this is already working great, thanks for the help mrflick.